# Validating a date with C# and ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a simple class to ensure the date entered into a form is a valid date. Where can I improve it, have I missed anything?

```
public class ValidDate : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var dateToParse = value.ToString();
        var parsedDate = new DateTime();

        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateToParse, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        return new ValidationResult("Invalid date, please try again with a valid date in the format of DD/MM/YYYY.");
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I would consider to include the malformed input data into the error message. It can help a lot during investigation.

Comment: @PeterCsala that's a good shout, thanks, I'll add that in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could easily turn your method into a one-liner [expression-bodied method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#methods) with a few tricks:

- use the `_` [discard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) variable instead of the explicit `parsedDate` variable (also, it doesn't need initializing to `new DateTime()`).
- use the [conditional operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) since you're returning one of two `ValidationResult`s.
- `value.ToString()` can be passed directly into `TryParseExact` without the extra local variable `dateToParse`.

Giving:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) =>
    DateTime.TryParseExact(value.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out _)
        ? ValidationResult.Success
        : new ValidationResult("Invalid date, please try again with a valid date in the format of DD/MM/YYYY.");
```

Couple more items:

- Recommend -- for ease of reading -- adding a `using System.Globalization;` to your namespace so you don't have to type that long prefix out twice.
- As this is an attribute, add the suffix `Attribute` to your class name.

Answer (score 1):

I think other answer had some great points, also I would use fluent validation instead so your model does not need to have dependencies on validation attributes.

https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/